# What is the second 'of' referring to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ellipses, colons

> But it was a vision of democracy: of a San Francisco run by its people, and not the royalty who dance at the Fairmont.

Apparently, some words are left out in the sentence. I have come up with two possible readings:

> (1) But it was a vision of democracy, namely democracy of a San Francisco that was run by its people and that was not run by the royalty who dance at the Fairmont.

> (2) But it was a vision of democracy, namely a vision of a San Francisco that was run by its people and that was not run by the royalty who dance at the Fairmont.

Which one is correct? Or the sentence itself is ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, there are many rules in English that delete predictable chunks of clauses and phrases, generally by repetition so they can be reconstructed, as you demonstrate. Such deletions are very common, but they can be reconstructed because they're all rule-governed.

Comment: It was a vision of democracy. It was a vision of a San Francisco run by its people. Democracy = a San Francisco run by its people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon has various implications, introducing various extensions to the preceding statement. Here, it appears in its 'exposition/elaboration' role, clarifying by breaking down the initial statement and/or giving specifics.

*But it was a vision*

- *of democracy:*
- [a vision] of a San Francisco run by its people, and not [run by] the royalty who dance at the Fairmont.*

It was a vision of A: of A'  {A' specifies the vision more precisely by detailing what the vision was and one thing it certainly wasn't.} So I'd break this down:

- But it was a vision {of democracy}: {of a San Francisco [run by (its people), and not (the royalty who dance at the Fairmont)]}. 'by its people' and 'not [by] the royalty who dance at the Fairmont' both complement 'run', and the whole string in square brackets post-modifies 'San Francisco'.

.......................

This use of the colon is explained in an [article by Larry Trask at the University of Sussex](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/colon):

> The colon is used to indicate that what follows it is an explanation
> or elaboration of what precedes it. That is, having introduced some
> topic in more general terms, you can use a colon and go on to explain
> that same topic in more specific terms. Schematically:
>
> More general: more specific
>
> A colon is nearly always preceded by a complete sentence; what follows
> the colon may or may not be a complete sentence, and it may be a mere
> list or even a single word. A colon is not normally followed by a
> capital letter in British usage, though American usage often prefers
> to use a capital. Here are some examples:
>
> - *Africa is facing a terrifying problem: perpetual drought.* {Explains [specifies] what the problem is.} ...
> - *She was sure of one thing: she was not going to be a housewife.* {Identifies the one thing she was sure of.}